How to link WIP to INV in oracle EBS using PLSQL
I'm a new software developer and I need help joining WIP to INV in Oracle EBS. I sure do hope there are people here who have used or are currently using Oracle EBS since it's a pretty old software. Do you guys have any idea which columns can I use to link these two responsibility? Your help will be much appreciated.
I tried connecting them with just the primary_item_id from wip_discrete_jobs table and inventory_item_id from the mtl_system_items_v.
